# Potential values of `this` in functions accessible only by owner

Tags: solidity

**Background**

I am just learning solidity and am getting confused by certain applications of the  `this` keyword in functions. The general form of the functions that confuse me is below and the `onlyowner` modifier only allows the owner of the contract to call the function:

```
func myfunc() onlyowner {
    ...
    this.balance
    ...
}
```

**Question**

- Can `this.balance` only reference the owner's address's balance?
- Or can the owner call this function and references another party's
  address (IE: `this` == other party's address)?
- If yes can they do so selectively or only for all addresses
  associated with the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the contract. So `this.balance` means the balance of the contract. It never means any other address.

Comment: Does this have the same effect as setting the contract owner's address in the constructor?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The `this` keyword refers to the contract. It's unrelated to any concept like "ownership."

Comment: I misunderstood. My bad.